# Why is my model getting stuck at the PPO('MultiInputPolicy') line when testing my javascript version of JumpKing using stable-baselines3 and PyTorch?

Tags: javascript, python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

In the code below, I am trying to test my model for a javascript version of JumpKing, and its getting stuck on the line model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env, verbose=1)
basically, when I use the debugger and try to step over that line, I get this in the output, and it just gets stuck:
Using cuda device
Wrapping the env with a `Monitor` wrapper
Wrapping the env in a DummyVecEnv.

```
import numpy as np
import os

from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from stable_baselines3 import PPO

import asyncio

from env import JumpKingEnv
from game import Game
import time




models_dir = f"models/{int(time.time())}"
logdir = f"logs/{int(time.time())}"

if not os.path.exists(models_dir):
    os.makedirs(models_dir)
if not os.path.exists(logdir):
    os.makedirs(logdir)

game = Game()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(game.startGame(True))

env = JumpKingEnv(game)
obs = env.reset()

model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env, verbose=1)
TIMESTEPS = 20000
model.learn(total_timesteps=TIMESTEPS, reset_num_timesteps=False, tb_log_name="PPO", tensorboardlog = logdir)
print("done learning")
#model.save(f"{models_dir}/{TIMESTEPS*i}")
    #model.save("ppo_jumpking")
time.sleep(3)

for i in range(1000):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
    obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
#obs = env.reset()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(game.terminate())
```

I used some test code earlier, and didn't have any problem with it:

```
from stable_baselines3.common.env_checker import check_env
from env import JumpKingEnv
from game import Game
import asyncio

game = Game()
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(game.startGame(True))

env = JumpKingEnv(game)
check_env(env)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(game.terminate())
```

I looked through the constructor for the model, but I couldn't find any reason why it would get stuck like that.

Does it have anything to do with my observation space?
Currently, the space is a dict with 3 items:

- the map: a 900x1200 matrix of 0's or 1's which represent walls/obstacles
- player position array
- current level (int)

When I run check_env(env), i get
UserWarning: Your observation map has an unconventional shape (neither an image, nor a 1D vector). We recommend you to flatten the observation to have only a 1D vector or use a custom policy to properly process the data.